# While importing *.tif in PostGIS db using raster2pgsql command i am facing issue "ERROR: invalid memory alloc request size 1073741824"

Tags: postgis, raster2pgsql

I just need to import a .tif file into my PostGIS db. the TIFF file I have is 430 MB. While using this command following error is thrown:

```
 raster2pgsql -I -C -c *.ndvi.tif public.gistest1 | psql -U XXXX -h 
 localhost -d gisdb -p 5432

Password for user cropin_suhal: Processing 1/1: *.ndvi.tif

BEGIN    
CREATE TABLE   
ERROR:  invalid memory alloc request size 1073741824    
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored 
until end of     transaction block   
ERROR:  current transaction is 
aborted, commands ignored until end of     transaction block   
ERROR: 
current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of     
transaction block    ROLLBACK
```

The work around I did is to increase max_wal_size (integer)=10GB in postgresql.conf file but of no use.

Comment: So your app can't `malloc` a gigabyte in one go. Not unexpected in many situations. Now please convert this error message dump into a Question. You'll need to [Edit] to specify the exact software in use, a description of the data, what you were attempting to do, and what you have attempted to address the error.

Comment: I am trying to import a tif file into postgis db using raster2pgsql command. The size of tif file is 430 mb approximately. i have changed the max_wal_size=10GB in postgresql.conf file as well but no result.

Comment: I have deleted the cross posted one. Forgive me i apologise!

Comment: What is the size of the original tiff in pixels? You can check it with gdalinfo. You should probably use the -t switch for tiling your image http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/using_raster_dataman.html.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on the [comment from @user30184](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278181/while-importing-tif-in-postgis-db-using-raster2pgsql-command-i-am-facing-issue#comment443621_278181).

When doing the raster2pgsql command, you're basically saying that you are putting all your raster data in one row. This means that at 1GB in your row, postgreSQL is giving up on you. What I'm not certain of is how to know from your initial raster size when the 1GB limit will be exceeded, though it doesn't matter a whole lot to fix the issue anyway.

In order to be able to easily upload any size, use the tiling option of the great raster2pgsql tool, that is the "-t". I usually give it a "auto" setting, which gets the tile size for you based on the global raster size.

```
raster2pgsql -I -C -c -t auto *.ndvi.tif public.gistest1
```

Now, instead of one huge row that generate the memory allocation error, you get a bunch of rows representing your raster tiles.